# Descendant selector or Repeat same class in html

Tags: css, css-selectors

I should repeat class at all element that same

```
<ul class='nav'>
    <li class='sub-nav'>
        ...
    </li>
    <li class='sub-nav'>
        ...
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

or i should descendant selector
`.nav > li {...}`

I read this [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) to avoid descendant selector but i think repetition it's not good

what should i do?

(sorry i'm newbie.)

Comment: What are you trying to target, the `<li>` elements in the list?

Comment: hello newbie you got anything right? (meant answer)

Comment: Now i doubt what is the difference between use nav(className) and ul.nav(className)?

Comment: hmmm.. `.nav` if you use this class alone means you can use this class for anything div's, a's ,span's....so on, ul.nav means it is only for un-ordered list..for example.. `a.nav{}` here this nav class is used only for anchor elements. the class are used only for the respective elements..

Comment: "the class are used only for the respective elements." Thanks i get it ^ ^

Comment: Happie..:) if the Answer(below) is helpful Click the Tick symbol next to the vote.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i understand your need hmm instead of repeating the same class for styling  your `li` use   `descendant` selector and `child combinator` selector. [check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/3gTmG/8/)

if you use descendant selector means It will select any list items that are anywhere underneath an unordered list or any element you used in the markup structure.

```
ul.nav{
       width:500px;
        overflow:visible;
}
/*this one applies into whole li elements which cames under ul.nav*/
ul.nav li{
    background:#f8f8f8;
    line-height:30px;
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
}

ul.nav li ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0;
    width:100px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

if you use child combinator selector means it will only select list items that are direct children of an unordered list or any element you used in the markup structure.this one doesn't affects its children's unordered lists or any elements

```
ul.cselctor{
    margin-top:50px;

}

/*this one applies into direct childs (li) elements only which cames under ul.nav*/
ul.cselctor > li{
       background:#f00;
    line-height:30px;
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
}
ul.cselctor > li ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0;
    width:100px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

this is for your question in comment

`.nav` if you use this class alone means you can use this class for anything `div's, a's ,span's`....so on, ul.nav means it is only for un-ordered list..for example.. `a.nav{}` here this nav class is used only for anchor elements. the class are used only for the respective elements..